# Why applying TailwindCSS and custom CSS classes on RadixUi is not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13, radix-ui

I am using Radix UI with Tailwind CSS. When I apply Tailwind CSS classes or vanilla CSS classes on Radix UI components, the tailwind/vanilla CSS styles do not override the styles of Radix UI.

```
<TextField.Input
    className="[&&]:h-[57px] [&]:rounded-[8px] text3 [&&]:border-1 [&&]:border-solid 
    [&&]:border-second_black"
    placeholder="Enter your email"
/>
```

Should I have to add "[&&]:" to make that class a priority? Why is that and how can I have my CSS or Tailwind CSS to have higher precedence over Radix UI styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[&&]` increases [class specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#class_column), but you shouldn't depend on it since you never know to compete with the third party component's css how high the specificity you would need. It is hard to be consistent and can randomly break after some minor updates. (Though you can do something like `[&&&&&&&&&&&&&]` if you really want to...)

In tailwind you make a utility important by adding `!` to the beginning, so you should do:

```html
<TextField.Input
    className="!h-[57px] !rounded-[8px] !text-3 !border-solid !border-second_black"
    placeholder="Enter your email"
/>
```

However, for RadixUi Textfield, it seems like even if you omit the use of `TextField.Root`, it will still be generated along with a child `rt-TextFieldChrome` div (covered by `TextField.Input`). Hence, border styles need to be applied on both `Input` and `TextFieldChrome`. Otherwise, after adding the border radius on `Input`, the covered div will appear like below: (I've made the border radius and color more significant for better demonstration)

[image: Not selecting both child]

You can use `[&>*]` to select both or specify both `[&>input]` and `[&>.rt-TextFieldChrome]` if you have other components wrapped under `TextField.Root`:

```html
<TextField.Root className="[&>*]:!rounded-[50px] [&>*]:!border-solid">
    <TextField.Input className="!h-[57px]" placeholder="Search the docs…"/>
</TextField.Root>
```

You can observe this type of pattern across many popular libraries, such as MUI, and this complexity is the main reason why, when customizing these third-party components, we generally prefer to use the properties provided by the library. However, in this case, the interface provided by RadixUI is not enough to meet your requirements.

#### What is `[&&]` and why it works?

The use of `&` in tailwind are for [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants), where `&` represents the selector being modified.

First, lets take the document's example `[&:nth-child(3)]:underline` to explain how it works. Here `&` will be replaced by the current selector (the class name `[&:nth-child(3)]:underline` with a bunch of escape characters `\` to avoid the preserved css keywords) **and a dot in front**, generating this:

```css
/* Selecting elements with class name "[&:nth-child(3)]:underline",
   but only when it’s the third child. */
.\[\&\:nth-child\(3\)\]\:underline:nth-child(3) {
  text-decoration-style: underline /*this is the style from :underline*/
}
```

Now look at `[&&]:h-[57px]`, each `&` will be replaced to a dot and the current selector (the class name `[&&]:h-[57px]`), so the generated selector will be `.[&&]:h-[57px].[&&]:h-[57px]` which selects all elements with class `[&&]:h-[57px]` and `[&&]:h-[57px]`.

While selecting the same class twice doesn't make a difference on what elements are selected, since now there are two class selectors included in this CSS declaration, its specificity of the class column increases from 1 to 2, making it more competitive for its css chosen to be applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info, it helps. But still, its serious that our classes don't override the RadixUi component styles automatically. This makes customizing the component difficult and messy.

Comment: I totally agree. I'm not at my desk so I can't test the behavior now but maybe using `asChild`  with a native html `input` could be a work around... https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/guides/composition

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you.
I found this : [my style radixui has been overwritten by tailwind css](https://github.com/radix-ui/themes/issues/109).
It seems to be a `import`issue and they proposed some solutions.
Just try this : import all the radixui css into `global.css`. It worked for me.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import '@radix-ui/themes/styles.css';
@import './theme-config.css';
```

Before the team find a solution, i think this could be an alternative.